# Switch operation terminology confusion

Tags: switches, button, terminology

I was browsing for [push switches on Element14](http://au.element14.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?catalogId=15001&langId=43&storeId=10184&categoryId=800000004708&sort=P_PRICE&eq=N%3D203117%2B432%2B601%2B751%2B2101%26amp%3BNs%3DP_PRICE_FARNELL_AU%257c0%26amp%3BNtpc%3D1%26amp%3BNtpr%3D1&pageSize=25&beginIndex=1&showResults=true&aa=true&vw=) and due to the vast amount of choices, I wanted to narrow down my search. However I stumbled across the filter category "Switch Operation" and was confused as to the following terminology:

> X-X
>
> X-None-X
>
> X-On-X
>
> Where X can be either "On", "Off", "(On)", "(Off)".

Currently, I know the brackets mean momentary which I assume is the state when the button has to be held or pushed by the user. I also know that a SPST with switch operation of On-(Off) is a NO pushbutton and Off-(On) is NC pushbutton, but the existence of other possibilities just confuse me. What do they mean?

There seem to also be filters that seem to be weasel words. So there's "latching" and "Push-On Push-Off" along with "Push-Pull" and "Pull-To-Cheat". Are my assumptions correct?

I even tried to look in the datasheets but they don't really define much, like what is On-(On) vs On-On.

Comment: Can you link an example of "pull-to-cheat"?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1469107.pdf?_ga=1.32736507.418542624.1464679521

Answer (score 1):

A X-X switch has two possible (stable, for a non-momentary switch) contact positions, or a maximum of two throws if you will.  An X-X-X switch has three possible contact positions, or a maximum of three throws, although many of them are double throw switches where the third (center) position is an OFF position.

A "latching" switch is the same as "push-on push-off" or "push-pull" -- all of these mean that the switch does not have any momentary positions in it, although the position designator ("On-On" or whathaveyou) is the ultimate guide to this.  The manufacturer's datasheet should provide a schematic symbol or some other sort of usage documentation for the switch, as well.

Comment: But this is in the pushbutton category...

Comment: 3 state button? http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/698112.pdf?_ga=1.235482308.418542624.1464679521